# How can an object be unmodifiable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a mongodb function call that return a user object

```
User.findOne(condition, function(err, user) {
    console.log(user)   //  {username : 'blah', picture : 'blah', _id : 'blah'}
    delete user.picture;
});
```

somehow user object cannot be modified, delete does nothing. If I deep copy a brand new user object

```
var new_user = {};
for (var key in user)
    new_user[key] = user[key]
```

and do the deletion there, it works. Is there any situation where in Javascript when a object is not modifiable? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Can you show us the code that creates the `user` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed. Object properties can be made *frozen*, *undeletable*, *unenumerable* and not *configurable*. You can go check with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`.

```
console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( user, 'picture' ));
```

For instance.

If *configurable* is set to `false`, you can't delete that property.

Comment: @yngum: did you put that log before or after your `delete` statement ?

Comment: Object.keys(user) return buncha values, the actually object that contain all the properties is the a private one called _doc. and there is a __getter method that suppose to return the appropriate value? I will look further into how that work